# Reading data from child process one by one

Tags: c, printf, pipe

I have a code that creates two pipes for writing and reading data of 2 (to 4) child processes that call another program. The code of this program is simply two `printf`, one printing `-` and another printing `Done` both to the `stdout` which is connected to the reading pipe of the parent process.
In the parent process I read the data using

```
read(pipes[i][1][0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
```

The problem is that if I set the size of `buffer` to be 4 (for example) the `read()` call reads `-Do` which is not what I want, because I will call `read()` again after.
If the size is 2 everything works fine because I know the size of what I'm going to read, but in the rest of the code I don't have that information.

I tried `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()` on the child process but it doesn't work. I think this is really easy to solve but I cannot figure it out, is there a way to read the prints made by the child process one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sane way might be to use newline `'\n'` characters as separators.

Setting the buffer size to your exact message size is a brittle hack, in that it will break as soon as you add a new message with a different length.

In general anything you expect to send over a stream-oriented connection (pipes, streams or TCP sockets) needs either a message header with length, or a delimiter, to be reasonably easy to parse.

---

If you desperately want to treat each write as a discrete message, you could alternatively use a datagram socket, which actually behaves like this. You'd be looking for an `AF_UNIX/SOCK_DGRAM` socketpair in that case.

Comment: By using a newline you mean I will have to read char by char and stop when `'\n'` is found?

Comment: Well, you could just use `fgets` or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I will use that solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the buffer to be 5 and when doing the first read() to read "-". Read only 1 character by doing following:

```
read(pipes[i][1][0], buffer, 2);
```

And after that when you do the second read. Read 4 characters by doing:

```
read(pipes[i][1][0], buffer, 4);
```

The size of the buffer is set to 5 to contain the \0 character in the end, if you want to do string  operations to check what you read.

Comment: This fixes the problem with the example messages I gave, but in the rest of the code I don't know the size of what I'm going to read, then it is not possible to do so.

Comment: But if you don't know the size of what you are going to read ahead then you have to do it by doing multiple reads.

For example if you are reading a set of commands/packets from the other processes. The other process can give an identifier of the packet that has a constant length. You can read that and then decide based on that the size of the next read you will do.

Or in other case if you know the order in which you will receive stuff then you can read them in that particular order with respective read sizes.